# How can I send a message from a VB6 application to my C# application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb6, communication

Hi have a VB6 Windows application (old.exe) and a separate C# Winforms application (new.exe).  They both run on the same Windows machine.

I have access to both the VB6 and the C# source code, but the apps need to remain separate.

If both are running and have knowledge of each other (process Id), **what's the best way to send a message from one window to the other?**

**Update:**

In this case, I'm only talking about very infrequent and small messages - e.g. change the tab you're looking at using a small message like, "Invoice 67"

Bi-directional messaging would be great, but VB6 to .Net is the most important.

Comment: Tell us what kind of messaging you need (how big and how frequent are the messages - one way or bidirectional - etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the two prior answers consider the fact that this may be a multi-tentant environment or even span you domain.  As you move into distributed systems you shold consider messaging as opposed to inter-process communication, which over time will limit scalability.

For on-premise solutions consider MSMQ, there is a multitude of documentation out there, demonstrating the simplicity of this messaging infrastructure.

for broader scenarios, you should consider Windows Azure Storage Queues, you get an almost identical usability, but with a broader accessibility and improved management tools.

MSMQ is domain-specific, by Azure spans the globe.

Comment: "If both are running and have knowledge of each other (process Id), what's the best way to send a message from one window to the other?" Implies they are running on the same box.

Comment: ahh, distributed systems - definitely not in my case, but good question. I'll clarify in the question

Comment: why would you have the two directly communicate? there is not reason for any two applications to talk directly to one another besides the strictest security.  otherwise, MSMQ deployed on the local server will bring a breath of fresh air to this project along with a degree of simplicity.

Comment: A valid argument, but if there was an exceedingly easy way to do it between running applications on the same machine, I don't want to overengineer it so it'll work across the globe...

Comment: But yes, MSMQ might be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Clay's comments.

However, I'll take a stab in the dark and go with the most obvious answer:

.NET (w/ WCF) supports both IPC and Named Pipes for local intra-process communications.

Here's a link on the topic using named pipes... but it's super old, and doesn't use WCF like it should... but the point is the same: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp  Updated version using WCF: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Comment: Both IPC and Named Pipes are trivial to implement in VB6. Of course, there is always COM Interop if you just don't feel like it.... so yes, really.

Comment: +1 for COM  Interop. Write a C# component that uses WCF to talk to the other process

Comment: @Steve Really?  IPC and Named Pipes are trivial to implement?  Last I checked, you really have to delve into the Win32 API.

Comment: @Steve I've seen the link before.  I am just saying that it is a massively non-trivial undertaking.  The moment you need to step out of the box, the learning curve will go through the roof.  IMO, just for the privilege of sending a couple of messages back and forth, it is not worth to learn a whole new paradigm.  I'd stick with something that's well known (such as something that's socket based).

Comment: @Angry, if that's how you feel, then great, go for it. I suppose the question WAS "How CAN I" not "How SHOULD I"... Because there are mechanisms built into the OS specifically to address the latter question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more-or-less complete list of IPC alternatives for Windows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Most of them can be utilized from VB6 and C# as well.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I have used for this very purpose is to have TCP communications between the processes.  It allows for bidirectional communication.  And as a bonus, should you ever move one of the applications to a different box, your apps will continue functioning with very little changes.

In .NET, you can use a plethora of classes for this purpose (ton of stuff from low-level to high-level in System.Net).  In VB6, you could go with the Winsock control that ships with the IDE.  I use Dart Winsock control (costs $$$), just because it is so much more flexible.

I set up both apps to send/receive XML fragments with a known schema.  There is typically an attribute that tells the other app the type of message being received, along with the payload.

Comment: Perfectly valid... but humorous given this is the modern equivalent of the joke answer I already posted: "Virtual Null Modem".

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution (based on the info provided):

Create a dedicated folder for incoming and outgoing messages (the one applications incoming folder will be the others outgoing folder)

Write messages (or data) into text/xml or other format to the output folder (adding a Source field so the application knows where its from)

Read the messages, based on date, and import messages/data

This allows integration to/from any application.

Comment: as i said, a basic solution, but fairly open. Thanks for the negative score. Good luck.

Comment: I'd really not recommend this. You can run into all sorts of problems trying to do this, not least of which is the issue of locking. It's not efficient either. There are plenty of good alternatives which are built for this purpose.

Comment: For the record, I didn't vote this down.  It is something we considered - not ideal, but it would work.  Assuming the "Good Luck" isn't sarcastic, thanks :)

Comment: +1, don't know who voted this down, it is a very simple but perfectly legal solution.

Comment: This idiot voted it down - and I don't mind saying so. I honestly don't understand why anyone would recommend this approach. Where do you store the files? When are you allowed to read? Can anyone just write to that location and have your app pick it up? Someone malicious? Why use IO on the drive needlessly? It's not reliable, efficient, or that much easier than the other options when you take into account everything else you have to deal with.

Comment: I know this is simple, but wanst sure if the information required persistance in the receiving application, and not sure if IPC is queued, which will overcome both applications not being open?

Comment: @Steve - might not change your mind, but have a read of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers.

Comment: If he says he knows the process IDs, then he has implied they are both running when the messages are sent. Anyways, MSMQ was built for that requirement; you can create a local, private, MSMQ queue. It's a cinch with WCF and not that difficult in VB6.

Comment: @Damovisa; Check my vote counts; 237 up, 15 down. I truly believe this answer is technically wrong - and it's doing anyone who takes this advise a disservice.

Comment: @Steve - I didn't think that'd change your mind. :) I have seen systems running using the filesystem for communication.  Is it the best solution? Definitely not - I wouldn't recommend it. Would it work? Almost certainly in my scenario.

Comment: @Damovisa; And I know people who still tack extra logic into Access '97 databases when they could be creating reusable WCF services in the same amount of time... but they don't take the time up-front to learn how to make web services - so they never do - and they end up with a worse solution. Implementing any of the other options would take someone who knew how to do it just as long as this option - and the world would be a better place. You could also do it with a null-modem adapter and two open COM ports... but that would just be silly now, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Steve, @Damovisa: I agree, its not the best solution for small and infrequent messages, in this case.

Comment: @Steve - Whew, ok. You are completely right. There is no possible way a fileserver-based solution would work. This answer is technically invalid.

Comment: @Damovisa; LOL... point taken... but still... "Works" and "Works Well" are two different things. Bubble gum might stop a radiation leak too... doesn't mean I'd recommend it.

Comment: @Steve - Yes, I agree. That's why I didn't vote this up. We have different thresholds methinks :)

Comment: @Damovisa; and maybe I'm just cranky right now : ) Anyways, best of luck to you. That was fun. I got my rant out for the night.

Comment: @Mark; Please feel free to downvote my alternative answer entitled: "The Ultimate Answer To This Question" as my penance for being cranky : )

Comment: I just checked my votes (938 up, 7 down) I only downvote on stupidity, or maybe if I am cranky too. I think my answer was premature to the additional information supplied in this case, but this type of mechanism has its uses and is still seen today in industry, especially for systems that need to be open to all sorts of platforms and devices (not mobiles). For instance the printing industry (in my opinion) is a total hack when it comes to integration. Even the Royal Mail (as seen whilst integrating to a recent system) take the file based approach.

Answer (score -1):

### The Ultimate Answer To This Question

VIRTUAL NULL MODEM:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem#Virtual_null_modem

From Wikipedia:

> A virtual null modem is a
>   communication method to connect two
>   computer applications directly using a
>   virtual serial port. Unlike a null
>   modem cable, a virtual null modem is a
>   software solution which emulates a
>   hardware null modem within the
>   computer. All features of a hardware
>   null modem are available in a virtual
>   null modem as well. There are some
>   advantages to this:
>
> Higher transmission speed of serial data (limited by computer performance 
>   only). Virtual connection over network or Internet is possible, mitigating cable
>   length restrictions.
>   An unlimited number of virtual connections is possible.
>   No serial cable is needed.
>   The computer's physical serial ports remain free.
>
> For instance, DOSBox has allowed older
>   DOS games to use virtual null modems.
>
> Another common example consists of
>   unix pseudo terminals (pty) which
>   present a standard tty interface to
>   user applications, including virtual
>   serial controls. Two such ptys may
>   easily be linked together by an
>   application to form a virtual null
>   modem communication path.

With the HIGHLIGHT of this solution being: IT REQUIRES **NO CABLES**!!!

*Note; This is an attempt at humor. Forgive me if it's not funny.

Comment: ROFL... NO CABLES!? AMAZING! And a BLAZING 9600 baud! It's practically magic.

Comment: I love how the article actually says "There are some advantages to this: [...]"... that's the best part.

Comment: I hope it was Mark who downvoted this... because, if not, the irony is wonderful.